# Flutter APK build android resource linking failed vibrate package

Tags: flutter, gradle, androidx, flutter-dependencies, android-build

I'm trying to build an apk for my app but I get a resource linking fail on the vibrate package.
I can run my app in release mode and I can also build an app bundle without failure.
I already did a successful apk build two days ago, what I changed since this build:
-upgrading to Android studio 4.0
-run a pub cache repair (due to an other error resolved now)

Error I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':vibrate:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\plest\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1aeb117cf01e0e03a347b2b45aacb6fb\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

     C:\Users\plest\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1aeb117cf01e0e03a347b2b45aacb6fb\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

     C:\Users\plest\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1aeb117cf01e0e03a347b2b45aacb6fb\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.

     C:\Users\plest\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1aeb117cf01e0e03a347b2b45aacb6fb\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\plest\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1aeb117cf01e0e03a347b2b45aacb6fb\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s







Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           24,3s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                     
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My flutter doctor is good and a flutter clean doesn't change anything.
I can't access the flutter panel when right click on the android panel.

[image]

EDIT:
if I run with verbose I get this in my log

```
[  +17 ms] > Task :vibrate:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :vibrate:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :vibrate:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :vibrate:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :vibrate:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :vibrate:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[   +2 ms] > Task :vibrate:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :vibrate:bundleDebugAar UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :vibrate:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :vibrate:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[ +253 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
[   +1 ms] Unable to strip library
'C:\Users\plest\StudioProjects\the_spot\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\debug\out\lib\x86\libflutter.so' due to
missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
[  +97 ms] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
[   +1 ms] Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
[   +1 ms] Unable to strip library
'C:\Users\plest\StudioProjects\the_spot\build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\debug\out\lib\x86_64\libflutter.so' due
to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue upgrading vibrate 0.0.4 to flutter_vibrate 1.0.0